# How do I save/read to a file

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, passwords

so I have made my code and it works and everything but... now it says that I have to save it to a file. Here's my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace Case3Password
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            bool que = false;
            while (que == false)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Choose whether to login, make or change");
                string command = Console.ReadLine();
                if (command == "make" && !MadeAccount)
                {
                    MakeAccount();
                }
                else if (command == "change" && MadeAccount)
                {
                    ChangePassword();
                }
                else if (command == "login" & MadeAccount)
                {
                    Login();
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("incorrect choice, type either 'login', 'make' or 'change'");
                }
            }
        }
        static bool MadeAccount = false;
        static void MakeAccount()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Input your username");
            string Username = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Input your password");
            string password = Console.ReadLine();

            if (ContainsUpperAndLower(password) == true && ContainsNumbersAndSpecialCharacters(password) == true && ContainsNoNumbersAtStartOrEnd(password) == true && ContainNoSpace(password) == true && UsernamePasswordTrue(Username, password) == true)
            {
                string folder = @"C:\Temp\";
                string fileName = "Dokumenter.txt";
                string fullPath = fileName;
                string[] lines = { Username, password };
                File.WriteAllLines(fullPath, lines);
                MadeAccount = true;
                Console.WriteLine("Account succesfully created");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Sorry this password doesn't meet the requirements");
            }
        }
        static void ChangePassword()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Input your username");
            string username = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Input your password");
            string password = Console.ReadLine();
            string folder = @"C:\Temp\";
            string fileName = "CSharpCornerAuthors.txt";
            string fullPath = folder + fileName;
            string[] text = File.ReadAllLines(fullPath);
            string PreviousUsername = text[0];
            string PreviousPassword = text[1];

            if (username == PreviousUsername && password == PreviousPassword)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("What do you want to change your password to?");
                string NewPassword = Console.ReadLine();


                if (PreviousPassword != NewPassword)
                {

                    if (ContainsUpperAndLower(password) == true && ContainsNumbersAndSpecialCharacters(password) == true && ContainsNoNumbersAtStartOrEnd(password) == true && ContainNoSpace(password) == true && UsernamePasswordTrue(username, password) == true)
                    {
                        string[] lines = { username, NewPassword };
                        File.WriteAllLines(fullPath, lines);
                        Console.WriteLine("Password succesfully changed");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Sorry this password doesn't meet the requirements");
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        static void Login()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Input your username");
            string username = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Input your password");
            string password = Console.ReadLine();
            string folder = @"C:\Temp\";
            string fileName = "CSharpCornerAuthors.txt";
            string fullPath = folder + fileName;
            string[] text = File.ReadAllLines(fullPath);
            string PreviousUsername = text[0];
            string PreviousPassword = text[1];
            if (username == PreviousUsername && password == PreviousPassword)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Succesfully logged in");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Sorry either your username or password was incorrect");
            }

            //6 metoder stillet op --->
            //Første metode har jeg kaldet LengthCheck og her har jeg lavet en if/else statement
        }
        public static bool LengthCheck(string password) 
        {
            if (password.Length >= 12) //Hvis password er større end/lig med 12 tegn så returnere den en true værdi
            {
                return true;
            }
            else //En else statement hvis nu den password er mindre end 12
            {
                return false; //Hvis den er ´mindre end 12 tegn så kommer den tilbage false
            }

        }

        //2. metode hvor jeg siger at password SKAL anvende både store og små bogstaver
        public static bool ContainsUpperAndLower(string password)
        {
            int i = 0; //det her er tælleren som bliver brugt senere i koden

            //2 booleans som begge er sat til at være false
            bool ContainsUpperCase = false;
            bool ContainsLowerCase = false;

            //Jeg har brugt en while-loop her som siger at password-længde er større end i
            //og UpperCase && LowerCase
            while (i < password.Length && !(ContainsUpperCase && ContainsLowerCase))
            {
                char letter = password[i]; //jeg har sat char letter = password[i]; altså indivduelle bogstaver siden at jeg skal tjekke alle bogstaverne igennem

                if (ContainsUpperCase == false)
                {
                    ContainsUpperCase = Char.IsUpper(letter);
                }
                if (ContainsLowerCase == false)
                {
                    ContainsLowerCase = Char.IsLower(letter);
                }
                i = i + 1; //Man kan også bruge i++ her. Det præcist det samme
            }
            return ContainsUpperCase && ContainsLowerCase;
        }


        public static bool ContainsNumbersAndSpecialCharacters(string password)
        {
            int i = 0;

            bool Numbers = false;
            bool SpecialCharacters = false;

            while (i < password.Length && !(Numbers && SpecialCharacters))
            {
                char letter = password[i];

                if (Numbers == false)
                {
                    Numbers = Char.IsDigit(letter);
                }
                if (SpecialCharacters == false)
                {
                    SpecialCharacters = !Char.IsLetterOrDigit(letter);
                }
                i = i + 1;
            }
            return Numbers && SpecialCharacters;
        }


        public static bool ContainsNoNumbersAtStartOrEnd(string password)
        {
            if (Char.IsDigit(password[0]) == false & Char.IsDigit(password[password.Length - 1]) == false)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }



        public static bool ContainNoSpace(string password)
        {
            int i = 0;

            bool NoSpace = false;

            while (i < password.Length && !(NoSpace))
            {
                if (NoSpace == false)
                {
                    NoSpace = Char.IsWhiteSpace(password[i]);
                }
                i = i + 1;
            }
            NoSpace = !NoSpace;

            return NoSpace;
        }



        public static bool UsernamePasswordTrue(string password, string Username)
        {
            if (Username.ToLower() != password.ToLower())
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }

        }

    }
}
```

I have tried to look up videos and look up online but I don't really see how I can apply either of what i've seen to my code so i'm hoping someone can help me in here. I've been stuck on this project for so long just because of this whole file thing. I've never really grasped or understood it. Basically I have to save the input from the user when they for example make an account/login/change password etc stuff like that.

Basically I need to Save login and password in clear text in
a text file. Which can again be loaded when logging in or when changing the code.

Comment: Except from the fact that you use two different files (Dokumenter.txt and CSharpCornerAuthors.txt) and currently are only able to store one account, you seem to be on the right track. What exactly is the problem? (one big caveat, though: NEVER store passwords in a file or database).

Comment: We don't know what you've seen so we don't know what the actual issue is. If you need to save data to a text file then there's information all over the web about doing that. Keep in mind that you are allowed to put your current project aside and create a new test project to experiment with reading and writing text files specifically. Once you understand the principles involved, then you can apply them to your current project. In all honesty, you really haven't tried to solve the problem yet. I know it feels like you have, but you haven't.

Comment: What I think Klaus Gutter meant was to never store *plaintext* passwords. Any stored password should be run thru a "key derivation function", like PBKDF2, But that might be overkill for what I assume is a introductory level assignment. You might want to read up on [Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/how-to?pivots=dotnet-7-0), as that is a common way to store structured data.

Comment: @JonasH I think it is pretty safe to say we can assume he meant "never store a _decipherable_ password". Which basically means: use whatever the current safe method is to store a password token to verify/auth against. Storing a (encrypted or not) password is not it. And we are even past simple Hashes ...

Comment: That said: I do not get why "beginner's" courses do that. Just have a lecture about safe indentiy privision ... but no: let's have them learn something that has become unsafe in the 80s and they actually **should not use** _**ever**_.

Comment: @Fildor, I agree. My guess is that they want an assignment that covers input and storage. But they could have picked any other topic, and done the "account" exercise after they have been taught to do it correctly.

Comment: @JonasH Exactly my point. It's like teaching to drive on a German Autobahn in a 30s Zone. You just don't do that.

Comment: @KlausGütter Hello, I have changed every one of them to Dokumenter.txt but I still don't see the file anywhere? Basically I need to Save login and password in clear text in
a text file. Which can again be loaded when logging in or when changing the code.

Comment: In `MakeAccount` you do not use the `folder` when constructing the path.

Comment: @KlausGütter Because when I do folder + filename it doesnt work. It just gives me an error when I run my code after i've written my username and password. The error says this: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException:  A part of the path 'C:\MyProject\Dokumenter.txt' was not found.

Comment: But `folder + filename` should then be @"C:\Temp\Dokumenter.txt", not @"C:\MyProject\Dokumenter.txt"

Comment: @KlausGütter yeah sorry, that's what I meant. @"C:\Temp\Dokumenter.txt" that's what it said. I really can't see what the problem is, this is just annoying me so much because it's literally the only thing I have left to do in my code

Comment: If you get a DirectoryNotFoundException on this, the directory c:\temp might not exist or not be accessible

Comment: @KlausGütter I've tried putting in directories that exists on the computer and even made my own directories but it still wont work for some reason. For example, I created a folder called "MyProject" then inside that folder I made a txt file called Cases.txt and now it should say @"C:\MyProject\Cases.txt" and I thought that would work but it gave me same error